# Qt commercial chart building and usage

Tags: qt, qtcharts

I am facing a weird issue wiht Qt.
I am working with Qt Quick 2.2 on ubuntu with Qt5.3.1.
I am using evaluation version of Qt enterprise.

I built Qt commercial chart with instruction as below.
Navigated to Qtenterprise/EnterpriseAddOns/Charts/1.4/Src directory.
executed the following commands.
qmake CONFIG+="debug_and_release build_all"
make
make install

I am able to run the samples and demos provided with qt. But all of them seems to created with QT 5.2 or before.

I am able to create a new QT Quick UI project also.
But when I am creating QT Quick application, Program is crashing and I am getting a SIGSEGV in file  charttitle.cpp line number 33 as shown in the below picture.

Please help if somebody have already came across such an error.

[image: QT error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using QGuiApplication. To use Qt Charts you want to use QApplication.